# How failover works in kafka along with keeping up replication factor

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to understand how failover and replication factors work in kafka.

Let's say my cluster has 3 brokers and replication factor is also 3. In this case each broker will have one copy of partition and one of the broker is leader. If leader broker fails, then one of the follower broker will become leader but now the replication factor is down to 2. At this point if I add a new broker in the cluster, will kafka make sure that replication factor is 3 and will it copy the required data on the new broker.

How will above scenario work if my cluster already has an addition broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup (3 broker, 3 replicas), when 1 broker fails Kafka will automatically elect new leaders (on the remaining brokers) for all the partitions whose leaders were on the failing broker.

The replication factor does not change. The replication factor is a topic configuration that can only be changed by the user.

Similarly the Replica list does not change. This lists the brokers that should host each partition.

However, the In Sync Replicas (ISR) list will change and only contain the 2 remaining brokers.

If you add another broker to the cluster, what happens depend on its `broker.id`:

- if the `broker.id` is the same as the broker that failed, this new broker will start replicating data and eventually join the ISR for all the existing partitions.
- if it uses a different `broker.id`, nothing will happen. You will be able to create new topics with 3 replicas (that is not possible while there are only 2 brokers) but Kafka will not automatically replicate existing partitions. You can manually trigger a reassignment if needed, see the [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any easy way to assign same id to new broker in automated environment.

Comment: `broker.id` is part of the broker configuration. You want to be careful when bringing up a new broker with an empty disk with an existing id. This will cause it to start replicating all existing partitions that were assigned to this id. This can cause significant load to the rest of the cluster. You typically mostly want to do that when the disks from the old broker are dead or if the old broker is unable to restart.

Comment: broker.id is fine but i fail to understand how will this happen in automated environment. How do I inform the cluster that new broker coming up needs to be assigned an id which just went off the cluster or I have to do this all manually.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving out partitions (which is another concept of Kafka):

The replication factor does not say how many times a topic *is* replicated, but rather how many times it *should* be replicated. It is not affected by brokers shutting down.

Once a leader broker shuts down, the "leader" status goes over to another broker which is *in sync*, that means a broker that has the current state replicated and is not behind. Electing "leader" status to a broker that is not in sync would obviously lead to data loss, so this will never happen (when using the right settings).

These replicas eligible for taking "leader status" are called *in-sync replica (ISR)*, which is important, as there is a configuration called `min.insync.replicas` that specifies how many ISR have to exist for a Kafka message to be acknowledged. If this is set to 0, every Kafka message is acknowledged as "successful" as soon as it enters the "leader" broker, if this broker would die, all data that was not replicated yet is lost. If `min.insync.replicas` would be set to 1, every message waits with the acknowledgement, until at least 1 replica exists in order to be "successful", so if the broker would die now, there would be a replica covering this data. If there are not enough brokers to cover the minimum amount of replicas, your cluster will fail eventually.

So to answer your question: if you had 2 running brokers, `min.insync.replicas=1` (default) and replication factor of 3, your cluster runs fine and will add a replica as soon as you start up another broker. If another of the 2 brokers dies before you launch the third one, you will run into problems.

Comment: `your cluster runs fine and will add a replica as soon as you start up another broker`: This is not true!

Comment: @MickaelMaison Are you sure? For partitions I would agree, you have to trigger rebalancing manually but I was under the impression a freshly launched broker would automatically pick up pending replicas. Any source for that? I would edit my answer then

Comment: What do you call "pending replicas"?

Comment: "replicas-to-be-made" or however you want to phrase it. I just saw your answer and it makes sense that brokers with the same ID are assigned as followers (maybe that's why I was under the impression it always happens), but still: What if broker 1003 is assigned as follower, dies and I start broker 1004. Will the topic forever reference 1003 as replica, a broker which does not exist anymore, and thus never create a new replica until I explicitly trigger it?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You need to restart broker 1003 or reassign the partitions to 1004, Kafka will not automatically do it for you.